# How does CountVectorizer deal with new words in test data?

Tags: machine-learning, nlp, data-science, sparse-matrix, countvectorizer

I understand how CountVectorizer works in general. It takes word tokens and creates a sparse count matrix of documents (rows) and token counts (columns), that we can use for ML modeling.

However, how does it deal with new words that can presumably show up in test data, that weren't in the training data? Does it just ignore them?

Also, from a modeling standpoint, should the assumption be that if certain words are so rare that they didn't show up in the training data at all, and that they aren't relevant for any modeling you might perform?

Answer (score 3):

I am assuming you are referring to the scikit-learn CountVectorizer. Not that I know if any other myself.

Yes, when new documents are encoded, words that are not part of the vocabulary(created from the training data) are ignored by the count vectorizer.

Example of creating vocabulary: (https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_extraction.text.CountVectorizer.html)

```
>>> from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer
>>> corpus = [
...     'This is the first document.',
...     'This document is the second document.',
...     'And this is the third one.',
...     'Is this the first document?',
... ]
>>> vectorizer = CountVectorizer()
>>> X = vectorizer.fit_transform(corpus)
>>> print(vectorizer.get_feature_names())
['and', 'document', 'first', 'is', 'one', 'second', 'the', 'third', 'this']
>>> print(X.toarray())
[[0 1 1 1 0 0 1 0 1]
 [0 2 0 1 0 1 1 0 1]
 [1 0 0 1 1 0 1 1 1]
 [0 1 1 1 0 0 1 0 1]]
```

Now, use transform on new document and you can see that the Out of vocabulary words are ignored:

```
>>> print(vectorizer.transform(['not in any of the document second second']).toarray())
[[0 1 0 0 0 2 1 0 0]]
```

With respect to the rare words that are not part of the training data, I would agree to your statement that it is not significant for modeling since we would want to believe that the words that are most relevant to create and generalize a good model are already part of the training data.

Comment: Excellent. Thanks Abhilash! That's what made most sense to me when I started thinking more deeply about what CountVectorizer and the TF-IDF transformers are doing with text and how text modeling of this type differs from other types where the features are necessarily fixed in both training and test.